# About/Over - right preposition to use in given context

Tags: prepositions

He's heartbroken **about** the end of their friendship.
He's heartbroken **over** the end of their friendship.

Which is the right preposition to use here? Do both work? What difference does it make meaning-wise which preposition you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that he's heartbroken at the end of their friendship?
I can't find the difference of using the preposition; over,about and at.
Over means about in the dictionary.
All of the meaning of the expression which a speaker says seem the same.